# Why does training one model in my script train all others?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am running a script where I am training several different models one at a time. They all have the same architecture but are trained on different datasets. The models are stored in a list. I call the models iteratively and train each one like so:

```
for i in range(len(model_list)):
    model=model_list[i]
    model.fit(training,label)
```

(Let it be known that the training and label datasets aren't shown as being updated for each model but they are)
Each time I train a model, every other model in the list has it's weights updated with the weights of the current model, which is not what I want. I want each model to maintain the weights gathered from their own fitting session.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: The loop iterate over all the models and train all of them. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: How are you creating this list of models? Like `[create_model()] * number_of_models`?

Comment: `training` and `label` aren't changed in your loop, so each model is fit on the _same_ dataset.

Comment: @TomRon I have different datasets for each model, I expect each model to be trained on their own dataset and to keep the weights they learn. Currently, at the end of all the training, all the models have the same weights as the last model instead of each having their own individual weights.

Comment: @ForceBru `model_list=[]`
`for i in range(num_DNN):
    model_list.append(tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs_list,outputs=outputs_list))`

Comment: @Alexander I didn't include the training and label datasets changing in the example above but they do iterate as well in my script

Comment: Looks like functional API doesn't create layer every time you call tf.keras.models.Model(). I think you have to create your models in the loop, not just calling tf.keras.models.Model() on the same input and output

Comment: @Andrey That did the trick! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like functional API doesn't create layer every time you call tf.keras.models.Model(). I think you have to create your models in the loop, not just calling tf.keras.models.Model() on the same input and output